# CasperJSでクロール中に、メモリ使用が 97% 程度まで上がり、 Killed と表示され終了してしまう

Tags: javascript, casperjs

CasperJS　であるサイトをクロールし、クロールした情報をデータベースに格納する処理を作成しましたが、クロール中にメモリが97%程度まで上がり、　`Killed`　と表示され終了してしまいます。

メモリを大幅に使用してしまう原因は、以下のいずれかだと予想しています。

1. クロールした情報を格納している配列が大きすぎる
2. `eachThen` を使用しクロールするページが多すぎる

1.が原因の場合、ある程度の数になったら配列情報をデータベースに格納し、配列の中身をクリア。その後、クロールを継続する方法、または、参考になるサイト教えて頂けますでしょうか。

また、 2.が原因の場合を想定して、 `casper.page` オブジェクトの `close()` を使用したのですが、

```
Error: cannot access member `customHeaders' of deleted QObject
```

と表示されてしまいます。原因を教えて頂けますでしょうか。

上記のいずれでもない場合は、原因、または参考になるサイトを教えて頂けますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

```
'use strict';

var i, e;
var targets = new Array();
var title = new Array();
var page = new Array();
var image = new Array();
var duration = new Array();
var video = new Array();
var ua = ('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5');

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  targets.push('http://example.com&page=' + i);
}

var casper = require('casper').create({
  exitOnError: true,
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug",
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false
  }
}).userAgent(ua);

casper.start().eachThen(targets, function(response){
  this.thenOpen(response.data, function(response){

    //タイトルを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumbInside>p>a');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      title.push(e[i]['text']);
    }

    //時間を取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.duration');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      duration.push(e[i]['text'].replace(/min/, "分").replace(/()/, ""));
    }

    //画像ファイルを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumb>a>img');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      image.push(e[i]['attributes']['src']);
    }

    //ページURLを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumb>a');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      page.push('http://example.com' + e[i]['attributes']['href']);
    }

  });
});

//動画ファイルURLを所得
casper.then(function(){
  this.eachThen(page, function(response){
    this.thenOpen(response.data, function(response){
      this.thenClick('#playbtn>a', function(){
        video.push(this.requestUrl);
      });
    });
  });
});

casper.thenOpen('http://localhost/add.php', {
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    'site': site,
    'title[]': title,
    'page[]': page,
    'image[]': image,
    'duration[]': duration,
    'video[]': video
  }
});

casper.run(function(){
  this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/826
ここを参考にし、modules/casper.jsに`newPage()`を追記し、
クロール処理に、以下のように、

```
casper.page.close();
casper.newPage();
```

を追加することによって、処理が最後まで完了するようになりました。

```
casper.start().eachThen(targets, function(response){
  this.thenOpen(response.data, function(response){

    //タイトルを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumbInside>p>a');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      title.push(e[i]['text']);
    }

    //時間を取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.duration');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      duration.push(e[i]['text'].replace(/min/, "分").replace(/()/, ""));
    }

    //画像ファイルを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumb>a>img');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      image.push(e[i]['attributes']['src']);
    }

    //ページURLを取得
    e = this.getElementsInfo('.thumb>a');
    for (i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
      page.push('http://example.com' + e[i]['attributes']['href']);
    }

    //処理を追加
    casper.page.close();
    casper.newPage();

  });
});

//動画ファイルURLを所得
casper.then(function(){
  this.eachThen(page, function(response){
    this.thenOpen(response.data, function(response){
      this.thenClick('#playbtn>a', function(){
        video.push(this.requestUrl);

    　　//処理を追加
    　　casper.page.close();
    　　casper.newPage();
      });
    });
  });
});
```